# Difference between h2 vs hibernate and MySql in general sense

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, h2

I am while building a spring web came to know about H2,Hibernate.
Earlier while I developed android app I used sqlite or mySQL database.
While using those in new platform I am little bit in a dark about difference 
among them.

My Current understanding is:

H2 and MySQL are both relational database management system

Hibernate is orm(object relational model)

I am little bit confused that if these three can be used in same application
or these three can not be used at the same .Please let be understand plain 
english and with a real life example .TIA

Answer (score 13):

Yes, both H2 and MySQL are relational databases.

MySQL is a server - based database - it runs as a separate process from your application, and is commonly used in production deployments.

H2 is a lightweight database, which can run entirely in-memory, or with disk storage, either in your application's process (embedded) or in a separate process. It is most commonly used in testing scenarios, and IMHO, not suitable for most production applications.

Hibernate is an ORM, and can serve to insulate your application from the particular database that you are using, as long as you stay away from vendor-specific features.

It is common when using Hibernate and libraries built on top of it, to use a stand-alone database such as MySQL in production, and an embedded database like H2 in test, with only some configuration files changing between the two.

Since you are using Spring, it is arguably better to use Spring Data and JPA than to use Hibernate directly. Hibernate is bundled with Spring Data and serves as the JPA provider.

Comment: *"database such as MySQL in production, and an embedded database like H2 in test, with only some configuration files changing between the two."*  Wierd statement as you are playing russian roulette when releasing then when using RDMS from different vendors...Pretty sure most DBA/programmers know that you should test and release software on the same RDMS, even the same RDMS with minor version numbers differences can cause bugs or unexpected performance issues where the optimisation is differnect between minor  versions

Comment: I agree. I didn't say it wise, I just said that it was common :-)

Comment: *"I agree. I didn't say it wise, I just said that it was common :-)"*  fair enough.. I personal would avoid following the herd through a river in cold weather and look for a bridge instead to cross ;-)  .. More or less meaning i do not take or add unnecessary risks with unmatching versions it is asking for trouble